# Output last occurrence of match in file

Tags: python

Hi this is my problem statement
File 1 contains lines like this  :

```
aaaa 1  
aaaa 2  
bbbb 1  
bbbb 2  
bbbb 3  
cccc 1  
cccc 2  
dddd 1  
dddd 2
```

File 2 contains these lines:

```
aaaa  
cccc
```

I need to find from file 1 the matching lines for the last occurrence- so my output to be like

```
aaaa 2  
cccc 2
```

I wrote this in Python

```
with open('C:\\Temp\\file2.txt', "r") as f1:
    list1 = f1.readlines()
with open("C:\\Temp\\file1.txt", "r") as f2:
    list2 = f2.readlines()
fo = open("C:\\Temp\\file3.txt", "w")

for x in range (len(list1)):
    sample_list = []
    i = 0
    for i in range (len(list2)):
        if list2[i][0:4] == list1[x][0:4]:
            sample_list.append(list2[i][5:6])
        else:
            continue
    if sample_list:
        fo.write (list1[x][0:4] + " last occurrence was: " + sample_list[-1] + "\n")
    else:
        fo.write( list1[x][0:4] + " was not found" + "\n")
```

Just curious if this is a good approach to solving this problem or are there better ways?

Comment: Does the order of the output lines matter?

Answer (score 4):

> so [I want] my output to be like
>
> ```
> aaaa 2
> cccc 2
> ```

is not entirely correct, because you actually want your output to look like:

```
aaaa last occurrence was: 2
cccc last occurrence was: 2
```

Anyway, I don't think that fixed indexing is a very good idea for this application unless there are surprise spaces for which you haven't shown examples. You're probably better off just splitting.

For both the first and second files you read and store into memory all of the lines. You could take that opportunity to do some processing in-line with comprehensions, for instance creating a dictionary that naturally drops all but the last value for any given key. I don't think that `range` is well-applied here, and you also shouldn't have a nested loop.

### Suggested

```py
with open('file2.txt') as f:
    needles = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    haystack = dict(
        line.split(maxsplit=2)
        for line in f
    )

with open('file3.txt', 'w') as out:
    for needle in needles:
        sample = haystack.get(needle)
        if sample is None:
            print(needle, 'was not found', file=out)
        else:
            print(needle, 'last occurrence was:', sample, file=out)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I absolutely don't appreciate being called a liar- where I come from to accuse somebody of lying is pretty serious. 
Is the actual program output slightly different from my problem statement? I don't disagree and I accept responsibility- but that's a long way from accusing me of prevarication.

Comment: @medhansu I'm being fecetious, but I'm sorry for offending you. Update your question to be more accurate and I'll adjust accordingly.